# Ordenação por data com Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, preciso ordenar minhas noticias de modo que a ultima postagem esteja no topo, a dificuldade que estou tendo é onde devo organizar meu array...
Essa questão é diferente da ordenação por data pq o HTML não esta sofrendo alteração.

```js
var noticias = []; //array de noticias

function atualizarLista(noticia) {
    var lista = $('#noticias-recentes-list');
    var li = $('<li id="noticia-' + noticia.id + '">');
    li.addClass('noticia');
    var p_titulo = $('<p>');
    p_titulo.addClass('titulo');
    p_titulo.attr('onclick', 'mostrarNoticia(' + noticia.id + ')');
    p_titulo.html(noticia.titulo);
    var p_conteudo = $('<p>');
    p_conteudo.addClass('conteudo');
    p_conteudo.html(noticia.conteudo
        + '<br>'
        + '<span>------------------</span>'
        + '<br>'
        + '<button onclick="ocultarNoticia(' + noticia.id + ')">Fechar</button>' + '<br>'
        + '<button onclick="mostrarAutor(' + noticia.id + ')">Mostrar dados do autor</button>' + '<br>'
        + '<button onclick="ocultarAutor(' + noticia.id + ')">Ocultar dados do autor</button>');
    var p_autor = $('<p>');
    p_autor.addClass('autor');
    p_autor.html(
        noticia.nome
        + '<br>' +
        noticia.email
        + '<br>' +
        noticia.data_publicacao);
    li.append(p_titulo, p_conteudo, p_autor);
    p_autor.hide();
    p_conteudo.hide();
    lista.append(li);
}

function salvar(form) {
    var titulo = $('#frm-titulo').val();
    var conteudo = $('#frm-conteudo').val();
    var nome = $('#frm-nome').val();
    var email = $('#frm-email').val();
    var data_publicacao = new Date($('#frm-data').val()).toDate('dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii');
    var data_atual = new Date().toDate('dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii');
    var noticia = {
        id: noticias.length,
        titulo: titulo,
        conteudo: conteudo,
        nome: nome,
        email: email,
        data_publicacao: data_publicacao,
        data_atual: data_atual
    };
    if (data_publicacao != undefined) {
        if (data_publicacao > data_atual || data_publicacao < data_atual) {
            alert("Sua notícia foi salva, mas ainda não foi publicada! Aguarde.");
        }
        else {
            noticias.push(noticia);
            //noticias.sort(compare);  //eu pensava que era só fazer isso, mas não está dando certo
            atualizarLista(noticia);
            alert("Notícia publicada!");
        }
    }
    //form.reset();
}

function mostrarNoticia(id) {
    $('.conteudo', '#noticia-' + id).show();
}

function ocultarNoticia(id) {
    $('.conteudo', '#noticia-' + id).hide();
}

function ocultarAutor(id) {
    $('.autor', '#noticia-' + id).hide();
}

function mostrarAutor(id) {
    $('.autor', '#noticia-' + id).show();
}
function compare(a,b) {                          // metodo para ordenar
    return a.data_publicacao < b.data_publicacao;
}
```

Gente meu problema é que ao adicionar uma nova noticia, não atualiza a ordem no meu html de maneira dinamica...

Comment: A ordenação tem que ser feita obrigatoriamente do lado do cliente via javascript? Se sim talvez esse post te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: sim precisa, vou tentar aplicar essa solução aqui

Comment: o unico problema disso é que não atualiza dinamicamente no meu html

Comment: sim eu vi esse, o problema é que n atualiza o html, continua sendo por ondem de postagem, n pela ordem de ultima postagem...

Comment: Em que parte do código você utiliza o array "noticias" pra popular o seu html? Não encontrei.

Comment: ali na função salvar, no else eu dou um push

Comment: O push apenas esta adicionando um item "noticia" no array "noticias". Pra atualizar o html tem que ler esse array(que foi ordenado pela funcao sort) e renderizar novamente o HTML